# command sudo dpkg -r PacketTracer not working

Tags: uninstall

I have installed Cisco Packet Tracer from Cisco-PT-601.bin. But I cannot open it. When I tried to remove/uninstall using *sudo dpkg -r PacketTracer*, it said there is no installed package matching PacketTracer.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Please suggest any solution this problem. I am lacking in my CCNA course due to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

First You can find installed  Cisco Packet Tracer installed package using

```
 sudo dpkg --list | grep packettracer
```

You will get output something like `packettracer:i386`

Remove package using

```
sudo dpkg -r packettracer:i386
```